# The name 'XXXX' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
public void SetTextBoxValues(string[] values)
{
     if ( values.Length != TextBoxCount )
     {
         throw ( new ArgumentException( "There must be " + ( TextBoxCount + 1 ) + 
         " strings in the array" ));
     }

     else
     {
          accountTextBox.Text = values[ ( int ) TextBoxIndices.ACCOUNT ];
          firstNameTextBox.Text = values[ ( int ) TextBoxIndices.FIRST ];
          lastNameTextBox.Text = values[ ( int ) TextBoxIndices.LAST ];
          balanceTextBox.Text = values[ ( int ) TextBoxIndices.BALANCE ];
     } // end else
 } // end method SetTextBoxValues

 public string[] GetTextBoxValues()
 {
      string[] values = new string[TextBoxCount];
      values[(int)TextBoxIndices.ACCOUNT] = accountTextBox.Text;
      values[(int)TextBoxIndices.FIRST] = firstNameTextBox.Text;
      values[(int)TextBoxIndices.LAST] = lastNameTextBox.Text;
      values[(int)TextBoxIndices.BALANCE] = balanceTextBox.Text;
      return values;
 } // end method GetTextBoxValues
```

I need to know the problem for having the error in `accountTextBox` below:

```
the name 'accountTextBox' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Well, you don't declare it anywhere we can see.  Where do you expect the variable to come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** from the error and also from your code it is clear that there is no `TextBox` control with name `accountTextBox` on your Form.

**Solution :** you can create a `TextBox` control on Form with name `accountTextBox`.